# Replace periods and commas with space in each file within the folder

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains a group of files, and each file contains a text string, periods, and commas. I want to replace the periods and commas with spaces and print all the files afterwards.

I used Replace, but this error appeared to me:

```
attributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How can i solve it?

codes.py:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import os

# 1-stop word processing
stop_words_list = stopwords.words('english')
additional_stopwords = []

with open("C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/IR Homework/stop words.txt", 'r') as file:
    for word in file:
        word = word.split('\n')
        additional_stopwords.append(word[0])

stop_words_list += additional_stopwords
# --------------

# 2-tokenize and stemming
dir_path = 'C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'
save_dir = "C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Files_Without_SW/"

for document in os.listdir(dir_path):
    with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
        save_file = open(save_dir + document, 'w')
        text = reader.read()

        tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text if (word not in stop_words_list)]
        
        cleaned = tokens_without_sw.replace(',', ' ')
        cleaned = cleaned.replace('.', ' ')
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        text_tokens = word_tokenize(cleaned)

        save_file.writelines(["%s " % item for item in text_tokens])

        # cleaned = (" ").join(tokens_without_sw)

        print(document, ':', tokens_without_sw)

        with open("../Files/stemmer_words.txt", "a+") as stemFile:
            for stemWord in tokens_without_sw:
                stemFile.write(stemWord)
                stemFile.write(":")
                stemFile.write(ps.stem(stemWord))
                stemFile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [mre]. Also your questions seems to include multiple smaller questions. Try break it into smaller, much simpler questions. That said, you have an error here `tokens_without_sw.replace(',', ' ')` because in the line before that you create a list of words. `.replace()`can however only be used with strings. To get a string of that list of words use: `cleaned = ' '.join(tokens_without_sw).replace(',', ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use the string function "replace" on a list. If your intention is to use it on all of the list's members, you can do it like so:

```py
cleaned = [item.replace(',', ' ') for item in tokens_without_sw]
cleaned = [item.replace('.', ' ') for item in cleaned]
```

You can even take it one step forward and do both of the replaces at once, instead of doing two list comprehensions.

```py
cleaned = [item.replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ' ') for item in tokens_without_sw]
```

Another way without list comprehensions was mentioned in the comments by Andreas.